# Is there a way make tests Flask and Firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, flask, testing

I have a Flask app. Authentication is provided by Google Firebase. I want to make url tests with any Python/Flask libraries? Is there a way?

For example: /api/getBooks and I want to test url response 200 or not. There are some tools on Javascript like mocha and chai but I don't know any libraries on Flask or Firebase.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/overview/) springs to mind, although depending on the complexity of your app you might be able to just use the `requests` library...